# Menu bar with position fixed not working

Tags: css, html, menubar

Menu bar is fixed on the top of the page while scrolling down. However, it is weird that while scrolling down, the menu bar goes under other div so I cannot click the menu.

```css
#cssmenu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #E6E6E4;
}

.row {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.col-sm-4 {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul class="menubar">
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">Please</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">Fix</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">This</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">Problem</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class='row'>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the HTML code.

It is weird that it works well with other div that are not using those classes(container-fluid and row). Please help me to fix this prlbem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `z-index` to `#cssmenu` to make link clickable as below,

> The z-index CSS property specifies the z-order of a positioned element
>   and its descendants. When elements overlap, z-order determines which
>   one covers the other.

```
#cssmenu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #E6E6E4;
  z-index:9;/*Add this*/
}
```

```css
#cssmenu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #E6E6E4;
  z-index: 9;
}

.row {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.col-sm-4 {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul class="menubar">
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">Please</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">Fix</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">This</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">Problem</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class='row'>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. One more problem is that the menu bar now blocks the top of the container-fluid div. I want it to be placed right below the menu bar. Do you have an idea without setting "margin-top" for the container-fluid div?

Comment: Welcome @dsoup2 and no you have to use margin-top of same value as of it menu-bar, as it's position is fixed so you need to use margin-top in div below that. Do accept if it works.

Comment: lol I didn't know how to accept the answer until I pressed the check mark for curiosity. Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

See the code it is completely fine.

```css
#cssmenu {
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #E6E6E4;
}

#cssmenu ul li{
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.row{
margin:0 auto;
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
}
.col-sm-4{
height: 100%;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul class = "menubar">
            <li><a href = "#" class = "btn btn-sm">Please</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#" class = "btn btn-sm">Fix</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#" class = "btn btn-sm">This</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#" class = "btn btn-sm">Problem</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class = 'row'>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Omi236/pen/gRZYQZ?editors=1100

Comment: If you have specified z-index for other divs then assign heigher z-index to the menubar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope you got the solution

```css
#cssmenu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #E6E6E4;
}
.menubar{float:left;padding:0;margin:0;}
.menubar li{display:inline-block;float:left;}
.menubar li a{padding:10px;text-decoration:none;display:block;}

.row {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.col-sm-4 {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul class="menubar">
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">Please</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">Fix</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">This</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">Problem</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class='row'>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```